# Optional<T> when isPresent() get property or null when it is null; functional style in Java 8

Tags: java, spring, java-8, functional-programming, option-type

When I retrieve a Student entity from DB, the repository returns a nullable `Optional<Student>`. It has a `birthdate` field.

```
Optional<Student> getStudentById(String id);
```

So, how can I write in functional style a one-liner to get the birthdate of it, when it is null returns null, and when is not, return the date?

I am now with:

```
Date birthdate = studentRepository.getStudentById(id).isPresent() ? 
                    studentRepository.getStudentById(id).get().getBirthdate() : null;
```

But I think it is ugly to use `isPresent()` and ternary; it is just `if/else`.

And, this will not work:

```
Date birthdate = studentRepository.getStudentById(id).get().getBirthdate().orElse(null); // this does not work because orElse() cannot chain with getBirthdate()
```

I am with Java 8.

I don't think it is possible without any overhead but I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
studentRepository.getStudentById(id)
           .map(Student::getBirthdate).orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 6):

you can `map` it and use `orElse` to return the value if present or else provide a default:

```
studentRepository.getStudentById(id)
                 .map(Student::getBirthdate)
                 .orElse(defaultValue);
```

in your case, `defaultValue` would be `null`.